# What does @@procid mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Problem:** I have a query file that have a `@@procid` statement. I want to know the use and meaning of this. I'm new on this, sorry if it is silly.

**Question:** On my searches, on [this site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174408.aspx), I learned that it returns the procedure id of current Transact-SQL module, but what is this? What does "Transact-SQL module" mean? It should not return the remainder of some division([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx))? I didn't get the example showed on that page.

Or did I misunderstand this?

Comment: It's not *modulo* or *modulus*, it's *module*. It has nothing to do with the remainder of some division - they're different words.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The @@procid is the identifier associated with the current executing stored procedure, trigger, or user defined function.  It is an internal number sql server uses to keep track of these items in the system.  So with this id you can look up what object is associated with it. So in the following example:

`SET @ProcName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID);`

Gets the procedure name, because OBJECT_NAME is a function which gets the name from the `@@PROCID`.

The example is a little contrived, because the question ultimately becomes 'why not just hard code the name?'  The point of @@Proc is so that if you don't know what is executing (maybe dynamic code or such), you have a way of determining what is being executed at that point in time without having to hard code that information everywhere.

Comment: Thanks! This suits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Borrowing from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735864/1225845), `Module` is a term for a stored procedure, a stored function, a trigger or a view definition. When you create one of these objects in a SQL database, it creates an entry in the system tables, including the table `sys.sql_modules`.  These are given an `OBJECT_ID`, which you can use to identify them (and which the system function `@@PROCID` is coded to return).

The second item in your question, the [`MODULO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx) function, returns the remainder of a division: e.g., three divided by three has a remainder of 0, four divided by three has a remainder of 1, and five divided by three has a remainder of 2.

Though they are worlds apart in terms of use, there is a one-letter difference between the two: the first ends with an 'E' (MODUL**E**), while the second ends in an 'O' (MODUL**O**).

Comment: Yeah, i just saw it now. Sorry for that, and thanks!